# A problematic etymology of a 'three-letter' Russian profanity

Tags: этимология

Namely, a conjecture: `хуй < ховать`.
**Can it be a worthy version? Or why not?**

To my surprise I’ve found [a discussion](http://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=7470.0)
where this version does not look like something absolutely groundless (to me).

Just one solid argument will be enough if `ховать` (proto)forms/roots cannot be a source of `хуй`.
Particularly I wonder if the questioned hypothesis is inconsistent with some language paradigm(s) and/or needs to be a unique case of something.

*A question apparently for experts, please. The Internet is already full of popular (quasi/pseudo)argumentation that gives me nothing.*
*(I understand that answering it can be a labour and discussing the discussed (already somewhere else) can be impolitely off-communitic, so deleting the question is OK.)*

Comment: Please don't use expletives in the title (they are ok in the body and tags, but not in the title). While this site is about all aspects of language, profanity included, the titles might appear on the side widget on another sites.

Answer (score 1):

As one of comments in the discussion points out, this "explanation" comes from an old joke.

Comment: Комментарий уже удален. Пожалуйста, дайте развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this version doesn't make any sense.The real source of the word *хуй* is an ancient Slavic root *ху-*, which means *sprout* or *outgrowth*.

Comment: Could you please cite your source?